# freemarker templates check if sequence is empty

Tags: java, freemarker

I would like to check if a sequence is empty in a freemarker template.

This snippet works to check if a sequence ***contains*** a value:

```
<#if node.attachments?seq_contains("blue")>
  <pre>hello</pre>
</#if>
```

However, if `node.attachments` is empty i would like to do something else.

That is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try:

```
<#if node.attachments?size != 0>
```

Or:

```
<#if node.attachments?has_content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking against size of zero. I do NOT suggest using ?has_content becasue of the following:

```
<#assign new_hash=[]>
Check if the hash has content: 
<#if new_hash?has_content>
    True - it is empty
<#else>
    False - something is there
</#if>
```

Results in:

```
Check if the hash has content: False - something is there
```